# Stop playback of my voice when using mic during a call with twinkle voip

Tags: voip

When I'm making voip calls with twinkle I can hear myself via the speakers. It's not like an echo you might get in empty room for example. While this is useful if you're trying to check if your mic is working, it's annoying when you're trying to have a conversion. Constantly trying to filter out your own voice.

I'm using twinkle as my client. Is it my client or is it a setting on my ATA/ mic configuration?

Answer (score 0):

What is twinkle ? To answer your question, possible reason could be an additional mic on the laptop (if you're using one), which is picking up your voice.

Comment: no I don't have any other mics connected to the pc. Twinkle is sip client for linux.

Comment: I 'm using a logitech clearchat comfort usb headset

Answer (score 0):

Set the MIC input in your mixer to "Silent", but keep the "capture" flag set.

So the MIC input is not mixed into the Output signal.